# How to connect remote database via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to connect to Heroku's database via NodeJs.

I tried to connect to localhost and it worked perfectly. But when i tried to remote database it gives error.

Here is the localhost connection code which is working perfectly.

```
const conectionString='postgressql://postgres:1234@localhost:5433/Qfield'
const client= new Client({
    connectionString:conectionString
})

client.connect()

//client.query('select * from point',(err,res)=>{
//    console.log(err,res)
//    client.end()
//})

client.query('SELECT * FROM trees', function(err, res) {
    console.log(err,res)
    client.end()
    });
```

Here is the error connection which is remote database.

```
const {Pool,Client}=require('pg')
const conectionString='postgressql://Username:Password@ec2-54-228-243-29.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/database'
const client= new Client({
    connectionString:conectionString
})

client.connect()

//client.query('select * from point',(err,res)=>{
//    console.log(err,res)
//    client.end()
//})

client.query('SELECT * FROM trees', function(err, res) {
    console.log(err,res)
    client.end()
    });
```

Here is the error.

```
(node:14896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "193.140.225.88", user "vfoiltyjszbpav", database "dduigib0uc8ebt", SSL off
    at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\CBS Lab\Desktop\postgres_conn\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:604:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\CBS Lab\Desktop\postgres_conn\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:401:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBS Lab\Desktop\postgres_conn\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:121:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
(node:14896) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14896) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
    at Connection.con.once (C:\Users\CBS Lab\Desktop\postgres_conn\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:252:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CBS Lab\Desktop\postgres_conn\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:131:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

How can I fix this error? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `ssl=true` to your connection string to fix the error you've got:

```
const conectionString='postgressql://Username:Password@ec2-54-228-243-29.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/database?ssl=true'
```